# Docker: Running nano in docker container

Tags: docker

I open an interactive shell into a docker container like so

```
sudo docker exec -t -i {container_name} bash
```

So far so good but trying to run `nano` results in:

> Error opening terminal: unknown.

Comment: Which container is this? also what does your PATH variable look like?

Answer (score 199, accepted):

I think this can be related with [Docker Issue #9299](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/9299).

There are some workarounds commented in that issue:

- Run the container allocating a pseudo-TTY (option `-t`).
- Export environment variable $TERM=xterm in the container's process run in exec (i.e.: `export TERM=xterm`)

Comment: The main issue actually seems to be [this one](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/8755)

Comment: Allocating a pseudo-TTY didn't work for me but changing `TERM` did.

Comment: This issue is frustrating depending on the environment. For Centos 8 using Docker for Windows on Win 10, only `TERM=xterm-color` seems to work for me. [serverfault answer](https://serverfault.com/a/329308/158008).

Answer (score 123):

Run comand : `export TERM=xterm`

Comment: just to clarify. without restarting the docker container. apt-get install nano. then export TERM=xterm. Then nano file.txt. (This won't be around if you restart your docker container.)

Comment: Worked fine, just ran that command and then nano worked, no container restart

Answer (score 37):

You can add

```
ENV TERM xterm
```

to your Dockerfile if you will use the editor regularly.  We have that setting in our base container, since we're constantly debugging things with vi/emacs.

Comment: Somehow this is not working for me while `docker exec -it [CONTAINER_ID] /bin/bash -c "export TERM=xterm; exec bash"` works fine. I just added `ENV TERM xterm` before the `EXPOSE` statement, is that correct?

Comment: Nevermind, "solved" it. Basically I needed to add the `ENV TERM xterm` before the `RUN` command.

Answer (score 32):

```
docker exec -it id_container bash
apt-get update
apt-get install nano
export TERM=xterm
```

Answer (score 11):

as `$TERM` was already set to `xterm` but still not working for me, here is a way that worked: `docker exec -it [CONTAINER_ID] /bin/bash -c "export TERM=xterm; exec bash"`

Answer (score 9):

Run this command in your container `apk add nano`

Comment: Worked in a container that didn't have apt-get or yum. Thanks

Comment: simplemente con eso funciona 

Answer (score 6):

I did a workaround, in my .bashrc i have added:

`alias nano='export TERM=xterm && nano'`

In this case the error no longer appear

Answer (score 1):

For me `export TERM=xterm` causes some display issues described here:
https://superuser.com/questions/1172222/issues-editing-files-with-nano-in-bash-windows-10

In that case `export TERM=linux` may works better.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if we are talking about the same thing but you need to make `apt update | apt install nano` so you can install it in the container.